# Actualizar datos de una tabla a partir de otras pero solo a usuarios especificos

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de actualizar una tabla y en la condición estoy haciendo dos subconsultas para validar que existan los datos.

Si yo ejecuto mis consultas por separado, me muestra lo siguiente:

```
SELECT m.id AS membersid, m.name AS username, s.name AS skillname
    FROM skill s 
    INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id
    INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email
    INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name
```

[image: Query 1]

Y la segunda es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT b.id AS badgeid, b.name AS badgename 
FROM skill s 
INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email 
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name
```

Y me muestra los siguientes resultado

[image: Query 2]

El UPDATE para actualizar la tabla es el siguiente:

```
UPDATE sm4rtuniversity.badges_members SET active = 'si'
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT m.id
        FROM skill s 
        INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id
        INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email
        INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name)
AND badge_id IN (SELECT b.id
        FROM skill s 
        INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id
        INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email
        INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name)
```

El UPDATE si actualiza los datos, pero el problema es que me muestra 9 filas afectadas, como si los 3 usuarios tuvieran las 3 competencias asignadas, pero no. El usuario 102516 tiene 3, el usuario 102332 tiene 2 y el usuario 102265 solamente tiene 1. Entonces el UPDATE me tendría que regresar solamente 6 filas afectadas . ¿Alguien tiene una idea de como poder realizarlo?

Comment: Hola Guillermo, primero, podrias ejemplificar tu caso en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) a fin de darte una mejor solucion?(ni bien crees el esquema de tablas y hagas una consulta, compartes el linck que te crea). Y por otro lado, no entiendo cual es el producto final que buscas, a lo ultimo mencionas "como si tuvieran las 3 copetencias asignadas", quiere decir que quieres poner `Set active = 'si'` a aquellos que esten en todas las competenencias y `Set active = 'no'` aquellos que no?